# I keep getting this @bean error when trying to run my spring boot app with dynamodb and graphql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

This is the error which i am getting:

```
Description:
Field andiRepository in com.service.datafetcher.AllAndisDataFetcher required a bean of type 'com.repositories.AndiRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repositories.AndiRepository' in your configuration.
```

This is the data fetcher file which is requiring a bean:

```
import com.models.Andi;
import com.repositories.AndiRepository;
import graphql.schema.DataFetcher;
import graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.List;
@Component
public class AllAndisDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<List<Andi>> {
    @Autowired
    AndiRepository andiRepository;
    @Override
    public List<Andi> get(DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment) throws Exception {
        return andiRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

this is the main method which resides in "com".

```
package com;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.repositories")//to scan repository files
@EntityScan("com.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repositories.AndiRepository")
public class DynamoDBApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DynamoDBApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

The models, repositories, service, packages are inside the main com package.

This is the repository file:

```
package com.repositories;

import com.andiskillsmaxmodels.Andi;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AndiRepository extends CrudRepository<Andi, Integer> {
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify the full package name of the class where the `main()` method resides?

Comment: I will add it to the question, thank you

Comment: i have added it.

Comment: Is this a maven multi-module project?

Comment: im not sure what that means, but this is supposed to be a simple endpoint which receives a graphql query in the body and then executes it on dynamodb.

Comment: try changing `@ComponentScan("com.repositories")` to `@ComponentScan("com")` temporarly

Comment: Also, add the `AndiRepository` implementation class to the question

Comment: Done, it has been added to question

Comment: Why is your `AndiRepository` interface is in this package `com.andiskillsmaxrepositories` but in the `AllAndisDataFetcher` class you have imported `AndiRepository` from this package `com.repositories.AndiRepository`. And you have added `com.repositories` package to `@ComponentScan("com.repositories")`

Comment: I am so sorry that is how it was, i was trying ways to fix the errors and i uploaded the wrong version. When this was done originally all the package names matched

Comment: I have added an answer. follow that check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your package names. They're all over the place. You have imported classes from different packages it seems. Make sure that `AndiRepository` is in the `com.repositories` package. And `Andi` class in your `com.models` package. After correcting these mistakes do the following.

Remove `@ComponentScan("com.repositories")`. You don't need this, since `@SpringBootApplication`automatically does it for you.

And replace `@SpringBootApplication` with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com")`

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. The package names have been corrected and i added the annotation. The app starts but getting a 404 error. When i remove the component scan i get the same error.

Comment: @AmanKhan since you can run your program now, your problem has been solved. This is a separate issue. So you can mark this as the correct answer. For the `404` error it must be an issue with your endpoints or in the way you call your endpoint. Your endpoint cannot be found. That's what it means. So check your controllers properly. I don't have any experience with GraphQL. If it runs simillarly to REST, I may be able to help.